# SDK windows phone C# random.Next();

Tags: c#, xaml, random, sdk

i'm stuck while doing this set of codes, im trying to do a random.Next() for my phone game, everything works fine, but there's this logic error that i'm facing.

my game has two arrows left & right, the game starts with a random picture(which is either left or right), if arrow left<< appears i have to press btnLeft in order to get 1 point, if arrow right>> appears i'll have to press btnRight for the point, for my random.Next(0,2)     0 is btnLeft and 1 is btnRight.  the problem is when the first pic is generated randomly, lets say its the left arrow, when i press the btn, i am already pressing for the next random arrow, meaning the screen might be showing left arrow, but it have already generated the next random number, but the screen is still showing the left arrow, when i press btnLeft, i didn't gain score and the arrow changed to right>>, meaning i just lost a point, how do i solve this? .

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Navigation;
    using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
    using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
    using System.Windows.Threading;
    using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;


    namespace madAssignment
    {
        public partial class gamePlay : PhoneApplicationPage
        {
            int counter = 1000000;
            DispatcherTimer timer;

            int count = 0;

            public gamePlay()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                timer = new DispatcherTimer();
                timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1);
                timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
                // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
                //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
            }

            void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                //int num;
                counter -= 1;
                txtCount.Text = counter.ToString();

                if(Convert.ToInt32(txtCount.Text) == 0)
                {
                    timer.Stop();

                    Uri uri = new Uri("/gameEnd.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
                    this.NavigationService.Navigate(uri);
                }
            }

    int rand()
    {
        Random r = new Random();

        int p = 1;

        if(p == 0)
        {
            imgLeft.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            imgRight.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        else
        {
            imgLeft.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            imgRight.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }

        int i = r.Next(0, 2);

        return i;
    }

    private void btnTimerStart_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        imgLeft.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        imgRight.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

        timer.Start();

        rand();

    }

    private void btnLeft_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        if (rand() == 0)
        {
            count += 1;
            txtScore.Text = count.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            count -= 1;
            txtScore.Text = count.ToString();
        }
    }

    private void btnRight_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        if(rand() == 1)
        {
            count += 1;
            txtScore.Text = count.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            count -= 1;
            txtScore.Text = count.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing is that you generate a random number AFTER the tapping of a button.

What you want to do is actually generate the random number for the round, store it in an instance property, handle the input and only then generate and update the visibility of the buttons.

Also in the rand() method, you are setting the p variable to 1 explicitly, so this will always result in the left button not being shown and the right to be visible. I am guessing this is not really the visibility you want.

If you need any more help, please comment on this answer.

If this solved your problem, please mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: sorry im a beginner for SDK. i know what you are trying to teach me, but i'm not good enough to program it out by myself, as you can see these codes took me few days time. can you please tell me the code for the storing of instance and handle input and generate. and thanks for mentioning for the rand() method, i was testing out something, that was not a problem thanks a lot.

Comment: Please post all the code in your class, and also possibly the calling code as well so that I may be more able to help you. The code you shared is not adequate to understand exactly what you are doing.

Comment: hi i've edited, erm this is my code for the game play page, all of them, and what do you mean by calling code sir?